# Implement sidebar navigation in Twitter Bootstrap (identical to demo)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In this page: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html, the sidebar navigation scrolls up and then keeps a fixed distance from the top of the page.

Using CSS, position: fixed maintains a constant distance from the top always.

I cannot figure out how Twitter bootstrap accomplishes this. Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this part of twtter bootstrap helps you http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#affix

Comment: Thanks, I missed that they have a separate component for affixing.